# Grails deployment error on tomcat

Tags: grails, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy the grails app on tomcat using command

```
grails prod tomcat deploy --stacktrace
```

However, I am getting following error. Any idea how to resolve this? I am deploying it first time. App is working fine in development mode on my local machine (mac).

```
| Error Error executing script Tomcat: No such property: warName for class: Tomcat (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: warName for class: Tomcat
    at Tomcat$_run_closure1.doCall(Tomcat:30)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
| Error Error executing script Tomcat: No such property: warName for class: Tomcat
```

Comment: I'm not aware of deploy command in Grails command line interface also it's not listed in commands reference in official Grails documentation. Where did you find it?

Comment: check the grails tomcat plugin, http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat

Comment: grails prod deploy --stacktrace

Comment: @danielad are you if that commands work? I got error: Script 'Deploy' not found, did you mean:
1) DependencyReport
   2) InstallDependency
   3) RefreshDependencies
   4) CreatePlugin_
   5) PackagePlugin_

Comment: There's an issue open in the Grails JIRA: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPTOMCAT-8

Comment: @Klemens Thanks! There is patch given in the JIRA. Any idea how I can add patch? Second in future, in case, if I like to report the issue in JIRA of Grails, how can I do that?

Comment: 1. See answer by @SeattleStephens, basically it's about adding the line 'def warName = configureWarName()'. 2. Just sign up at http://jira.grails.org/ and submit an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not wrong, there is no command named 'grails prod tomcat deploy' there in grails. would be great if you let us know from where you got this command.

most of the deployment configurations are made for development by default, but you could change (Config.groovy, BuildConfig.grovvy and etc) them the way you need

may be below steps will help you.

1. Config.groovy

   environments {
      development {
       grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
       }

   **production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false

        // grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"

        // other production env related parameters goes here 
      }**
   }
2. BuildConfig.groovy

   along with dependencies and other configurations check for below entries

   //grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
    //grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
    //grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
    //grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
    //grails.project.target.level = 1.7
    //grails.project.source.level = 1.7
    grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war" //your project war file
3. run 'grails run-war' - this will run in production environment by default and gives you the war under given folder,
4. deploy the war in to tomcat.

Thanks
Motilal

Comment: I am trying to deploy the build directly from the terminal. The method that you have suggested, I already tried that and it is working fine. However the pain point is to upload again and again WAR file on Tomcat. Grails Tomcat plugin gives you autopilot support, AFAIK.

By the way, I got the command from this link: I got the command from here: http://flnkr.com/2013/07/grails-on-aws-ec2/

Comment: As noted above, this command option is part of the [Tomcat plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat)

Answer (score 3):

I also just ran into this and it's a known problem documented [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPTOMCAT-8).  The short term workaround is to modify the file

```
~/.grails/<vers>/projects/<project-name>/plugins/tomcat-7.0.42/scripts.Tomcat.groovy
```

As shown [here](http://jira.grails.org/secure/attachment/18553/quick_fix_for_GPTOMCAT-8.patch).